# Windows7 Shell Control Panel Custom Item like

Tags: windows-7, windows-shell

I want to know how we can achieve the same look and feel and functionality too to implement a configuration application in the shell control panel of the windows 7.

To register the control panel is easy, something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But what i want is to implement something for example like the UI of the "Uninstall Program" option in the Control Panel, an application like that without popping into a dialog or property sheet or a different process.

How we can accomplish this? MSDN has any section explaining how we can achieve this?

Thanks